# Spring Tiles + Validation when validtion has error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I'm working with Tiles 3.0 and Spring Validator.
How can I edit an user with ulr like .../edit/{userID} and has some validation error and then return to that view with the same url. My problem is the error did't show.
How can i do that?
Sorry for my bad English!

Here are my code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditUser(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {

    User user = userService.getUserById(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "user_edit";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@PathVariable int id,
        @Validated(GroupEdit.class) @ModelAttribute User user,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()){
        return "redirect:edit/" + user.getUserId();    //how can i return here?
    }
    userService.updateUser(user);
    return "redirect:edit/" + user.getUserId();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my stupid mistake.

Just return to the Tile (view) where reciving input from user when has validate error, and in that view modify the action form to match POST method. The URL of browser will be ../user/{userId}.

My View:

```
<form:form action="../edit/${user.userId}" modelAttribute="user" method="post"
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditUser(@PathVariable int id, Model model) {

    User user = userService.getUserById(id);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "user_edit";   //this is my Tiles definition in tiles.xml where user input data
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editUser(@PathVariable int id,
        @Validated(GroupEdit.class) @ModelAttribute User user,
        BindingResult result, Model model) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "user_edit";   //return to the Tiles in tiles.xml, it will show error.
    }
    userService.updateUser(user);
    return "redirect:../edit/" + user.getUserId();
}
```